# Powers of a unitary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to find the minimum exponent $M\in \mathbb{N}$, such that for a certain unitary matrix $F\in \mathbb{C}^{N}$,

$$F^M = 1_{\mathbb{C}^{N}}.$$

I don't think it matters, but it's the DFT matrix.
Now, I noticed that if $F^M = 1$, then $F^{M/2} = ({F^{M/2}})^\dagger$. However, I can't find a justification as to why M must be even. I'm not even sure if it has to be. (for the DFT matrix, M=4, though I'm still trying to figure out why it isn't 2)

Any ideas?

Comment: If $M$ is odd, then if $F$ is a diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are $M$-th roots of unity, then $F^M = 1$. So, there must be something special about the DFT matrix itself? Which (i.e., what size) DFT matrix are you looking at?

Comment: The definition I use is $F_{jk} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}e^{- \frac{2\pi i j k}{N}}$, for $0\leq j,k < N$.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that $N \geq 3$ is assumed too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that this comes from the [eigenvalues of a DFT matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors). Raising a matrix to the power $k$ raises its eigenvalues to the power $k$.

So, if the order of your matrix is $2$, you have $1$ eigenvalue equal to $-1$; when you have order greater than $2$, you have at least one eigenvalue equal to $-i$ (and, for order at least $4$, you have $i$ as well, but this doesn't change anything). See the table on the above link.

Notice that this does not hold for a general unitary matrix. For a counterexample, just take a 2D rotation by an angle $\varphi$ which is **not** of a form $\varphi = q\pi$ for $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ and no power of your matrix will ever become identity. Also, rotation for $\varphi = 2\pi/3$ will become identity when raised to the third (so, odd) power.

Comment: Yes. The problem is, that I can't use an argument about the eigenvalues, because I want to show the statement directly from the definition. The next thing to show then is that neither are all eigenvalues $\pm 1$, nor $\pm i$. Can I assume from the above, that $\lambda^4 = 0$ is the minimal polynomial? I think I would have to check whether there is any relation between F and its powers of lower degree, but maybe it follows directly. Another thing I thought about is assuming F diagonalized, but then I can't show that they can't all be $\pm i$..

Comment: Not $\lambda^4 = 0$, but $\lambda^4 = 1$. See the above link, it explains how is this seen.

Comment: Yes, of course. But for that argumentation to work (i.e. "all solutions of $\lambda^4 - 1 = 0$ are eigenvalues of F"), I would need that $\lambda^4 - 1$ is the minimal polynomial. Else I only get "some solutions of $\lambda^4 - 1 = 0$ are eigenvalues of F", or am I mistaken?

Comment: I need an argument, for why $$a1_{\mathbb{C}^N} + bF + cF^2 + dF^3 \neq 0 \quad \forall a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{C}$$

Comment: For the above (why is $M$ odd) it it enough to show that not all eigenvalues are $1$ (which would mean that $F = {\rm I}$). As for your last comment, you need at least one of $A,b,c,d$ to be nonzero.

Comment: Minimal polynomial $p$ of $F$ is the one of the least degree such that $p(F) = 0$. [You have already shown (with Dan Shved's help)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/440406/dft-matrix-question-eigenvalues-and-minimal-exponent) that $F^2 \ne {\rm I}$, so you have eigenvalues other than $1$ and $-1$ (I'm assuming order of $F$ to be sufficiently large). Since $\lambda^4 = 1$, candidates are $i$ and $-i$, so $F^3 \ne {\rm I}$, hence $p(\lambda) = \lambda^4 - 1$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$.

Comment: Well, I know that not all eigenvalues can be real, as else M=2 would suffice. But how can I see that there is at least one real eigenvalue? I just noticed that $\lambda^4 - 1$ can't be the minimal polynomial, as we start at $N=3.$

Comment: Assume that no eigenvalues are real. That means that all eigenvalues are either $i$ or $-i$. Since $F$ is unitary, it is (unitarily) diagonalizable, $F^2 = -{\rm I}$, which contradicts Dan's comment from the link in my previous comment (that some nondiagonal elements are equal to $1$).

Comment: OF COURSE! Thanks a lot, now it seems so clear.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.